# In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]=\{a+b\sqrt{3}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, show the following.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]=\{a+b\sqrt{3}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, show the following:

a) $1 - 2\sqrt{3}$ is not a unit,

b) $1 - 2\sqrt{3}$ and $8-5\sqrt{3}$ are associate elements.

Firstly, how would you show it is not a unit? It seems to fit the form $a+b\sqrt{3}$ quite well. For the second part, as associate elements, $1 - 2\sqrt{3}\mid 8-5\sqrt{3}$ and vice versa should hold, but neither do. Could someone help explain this?

Comment: You can use \lbrace and \rbrace to write $\lbrace$ and $\rbrace$. Regarding your question; **Hint**: Norms

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage, including but not limited to \mid. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

You say that $(1-2\sqrt3)\nmid(8-5\sqrt3)$. Let's test this out.
Consider
$$\frac{8-5\sqrt3}{1-2\sqrt3}=\frac{(8-5\sqrt3)(1+2\sqrt3)}{(1-2\sqrt3)(1+2\sqrt3)}=\frac{-22+11\sqrt3}{-11}=2-\sqrt3.$$
I reckon that actually $(1-2\sqrt3)\mid(8-5\sqrt3)$.
But does $(8-5\sqrt3)\mid(1-2\sqrt3)$? Over to you!

Comment: It does! It comes out to $2+\sqrt{3}$. Would you have something to say about the first part?

Comment: Think about $1/(1-2\sqrt3)$.

Comment: Rationalizing that leads to $\frac{1+2\sqrt{3}}{-11}$. Is that enough to conclude it is not a unit? Also, sorry to be a bother, but if you had any help with this, I'd be grateful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782591/show-that-for-each-non-negative-integer-k-the-set-i-k-i-k1-is-an-associa

Comment: Is that an element of $R$?

Comment: Oops, brainfart. Understood!